# python odeint gives strange results

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

I am trying to understand how scipy.odeint works, but I have some problems. For exampe:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import  odeint
from scipy.integrate import  odeint

def Diffeq(v,t, lam, gam,c, a):
    vdot = v
    for i in range(0,len(v)):
        if i == 0:
            vdot[0] = c[1]*v[1]- lam*a[0]*v[0]
        elif i == (len(v)-1):
            vdot[i] =  lam*a[i-1]*v[i-1] - (lam*a[i]+c[i])*v[i]
        else:
            vdot[i]=  lam*a[i-1]*v[i-1] - (lam*a[i]+c[i])*v[i]+ c[i+1]*v[i+1]
    print vdot
    return vdot



incond=np.array([0]*900)
incond[1] =1
t = np.linspace(0.0, 2, 1000)
ak = [2*i for i in range(0,900)]
lamma =2
gamma =1
c=[i*gamma for i in range(0,900)]

y = odeint(Diffeq, incond, t, args=(lamma,gamma,c,ak) )
```

This code should compute a system of differential equations of the form:
[image]

where

xdot_0 = -(a_0 + c_0)*x_0(t) + c_1*x_1(t)
xdot_899 = a_898*x_898(t) -(a_899 + c_899)*x_900(t)

with initial condition x(0) = (0,1,0...0)
when I try to analyse the results, I notice that my functions explode to + infinity. If I play with the constants ak, lamma, and gamma, I can get the results stuck in something like

x_k(t) = [0,-21,21, 0, 0,...,0]

at each operation. Therefore I am thinking that I made some mistake in my code, but I do not see where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, when you execute the line

```
    vdot = v
```

`vdot` is not a copy of `v`.  The two names now refer to the same object.  So when you modify `vdot` in the function `Diffeq`, you also modify the input argument.  If you modify `vdot[0]` and then later try to use `v[0]`, you are actually getting the modified value `vdot[0]`, so your calculations are not correct.

Change that line to, say,

```
    vdot = np.empty_like(v)
```

When I do that (and I remove the `print` statement, so the function finishes in a reasonable amount of time), `odeint` returns successfully.  Here's a plot of the solution components:

[image: plot]

Comment: Ok now it works, but, if I use 
    vdot = np.array([0]*900) 
instead of np.empty_like(v)
I keep getting strange results. why?

Comment: Don't use `vdot = np.array([0]*900)`; that creates an array of *integers*.  When you assign values to it, they will be cast to integer, which is definitely not what you want.  You could use `vdot = np.array([0.0]*900)`, or `vdot = np.zeros(900)`.

Comment: Oh that`s why. Thank you!